# Interleave Bits Generically

Tags: c#, mathematics, bitwise

[This commonly referenced "bit twiddling" site](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#InterleaveBMN) has an interesting algorithm for interleaving the bits of two 32-bit integers. Here is my attempt at completely generalizing the algorithm using C#'s generic maths feature; all "magic" constants have been replaced with functions and the primary loop has been unrolled for types that have a size of 256 bits or less.

**Code:**

```
public static TResult BitwisePair<TInput, TResult>(this TInput value, TInput other) where TInput : IBinaryInteger<TInput> where TResult : IBinaryInteger<TResult> {
    const int loopOffset = 7;

    int offset;
    int shift;

    var bitCountDividedByTwo = (int.CreateChecked(value: BinaryIntegerConstants<TResult>.Size) >> 1);
    var evenBits = TResult.CreateTruncating(value: other);
    var oddBits = TResult.CreateTruncating(value: value);

    if (loopOffset.NthPowerOfTwo<int>() < bitCountDividedByTwo) {
        var i = ((int.CreateChecked(value: BinaryIntegerConstants<TResult>.Log2Size) - loopOffset) - 1);

        do {
            offset = (i + (loopOffset - 1));
            shift = offset.NthPowerOfTwo<int>();

            DistributeBits(evenBits: ref evenBits, oddBits: ref oddBits, offset: offset, shift: shift);
        } while (0 < --i);
    }

    offset = 6; if ((shift = offset.NthPowerOfTwo<int>()) < bitCountDividedByTwo) { DistributeBits(evenBits: ref evenBits, oddBits: ref oddBits, offset: offset, shift: shift); }
    offset = 5; if ((shift = offset.NthPowerOfTwo<int>()) < bitCountDividedByTwo) { DistributeBits(evenBits: ref evenBits, oddBits: ref oddBits, offset: offset, shift: shift); }
    offset = 4; if ((shift = offset.NthPowerOfTwo<int>()) < bitCountDividedByTwo) { DistributeBits(evenBits: ref evenBits, oddBits: ref oddBits, offset: offset, shift: shift); }
    offset = 3; if ((shift = offset.NthPowerOfTwo<int>()) < bitCountDividedByTwo) { DistributeBits(evenBits: ref evenBits, oddBits: ref oddBits, offset: offset, shift: shift); }
    offset = 2; if ((shift = offset.NthPowerOfTwo<int>()) < bitCountDividedByTwo) { DistributeBits(evenBits: ref evenBits, oddBits: ref oddBits, offset: offset, shift: shift); }
    offset = 1; if ((shift = offset.NthPowerOfTwo<int>()) < bitCountDividedByTwo) { DistributeBits(evenBits: ref evenBits, oddBits: ref oddBits, offset: offset, shift: shift); }
    offset = 0; if ((shift = offset.NthPowerOfTwo<int>()) < bitCountDividedByTwo) { DistributeBits(evenBits: ref evenBits, oddBits: ref oddBits, offset: offset, shift: shift); }

    return (oddBits | (evenBits << shift));

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    static void DistributeBits(int offset, int shift, ref TResult evenBits, ref TResult oddBits) {
        var mask = offset.NthFermatMask<TResult>();

        evenBits = ((evenBits | (evenBits << shift)) & mask);
        oddBits = ((oddBits | (oddBits << shift)) & mask);
    }
}
```

**Helpers:**

```
public static class BinaryIntegerConstants<T> where T : IBinaryInteger<T>
{
    public static T Log2Size { get; }
    public static T Size { get; }

    static BinaryIntegerConstants() {
        var size = T.PopCount(value: T.AllBitsSet);

        Log2Size = T.Log2(value: size);
        Size = size;
    }
}
public static class BinaryIntegerFunctions
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    internal static T As<T>(this bool value) where T : IBinaryInteger<T> =>
        T.CreateTruncating(value: Unsafe.As<bool, byte>(source: ref value));
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    internal static T NthFermatMask<T>(this int value) where T : IBinaryInteger<T> {
        var x = T.AllBitsSet;
        var y = T.IsNegative(value: x).As<int>();

        return ((((x >>> y) / value.NthFermatNumber<T>()) << y) | T.One);
    }
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    internal static T NthFermatNumber<T>(this int value) where T : IBinaryInteger<T> =>
        ((T.One << (1 << value)) + T.One);
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    internal static T NthPowerOfTwo<T>(this int value) where T : IBinaryInteger<T> =>
        (T.One << value);
}
```

**Output Assembly:**

```
## Int32 | .NET 7.0.5 (7.0.523.17405), X64 RyuJIT AVX2
; Ouroboros.Maths.BinaryIntegerFunctions.BitwisePair[[System.Int16, System.Private.CoreLib],[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib]](Int16, Int16)
    movsx     rax,dx
    movsx     rdx,cx
    mov       ecx,eax
    shl       ecx,8
    or        eax,ecx
    and       eax,0FF00FF
    mov       ecx,edx
    shl       ecx,8
    or        edx,ecx
    and       edx,0FF00FF
    mov       ecx,eax
    shl       ecx,4
    or        ecx,eax
    mov       eax,ecx
    and       eax,0F0F0F0F
    mov       ecx,edx
    shl       ecx,4
    or        ecx,edx
    mov       edx,ecx
    and       edx,0F0F0F0F
    mov       ecx,eax
    shl       ecx,2
    or        ecx,eax
    mov       eax,ecx
    and       eax,33333333
    mov       ecx,edx
    shl       ecx,2
    or        ecx,edx
    mov       edx,ecx
    and       edx,33333333
    lea       ecx,[rax+rax]
    or        ecx,eax
    mov       eax,ecx
    and       eax,55555555
    lea       ecx,[rdx+rdx]
    or        ecx,edx
    mov       edx,ecx
    and       edx,55555555
    add       eax,eax
    or        eax,edx
    ret
; Total bytes of code 121

## UInt32 | .NET 7.0.5 (7.0.523.17405), X64 RyuJIT AVX2
; Ouroboros.Maths.BinaryIntegerFunctions.BitwisePair[[System.UInt16, System.Private.CoreLib],[System.UInt32, System.Private.CoreLib]](UInt16, UInt16)
    movzx     eax,dx
    movzx     edx,cx
    mov       ecx,eax
    shl       ecx,8
    or        eax,ecx
    and       eax,0FF00FF
    mov       ecx,edx
    shl       ecx,8
    or        edx,ecx
    and       edx,0FF00FF
    mov       ecx,eax
    shl       ecx,4
    or        ecx,eax
    mov       eax,ecx
    and       eax,0F0F0F0F
    mov       ecx,edx
    shl       ecx,4
    or        ecx,edx
    mov       edx,ecx
    and       edx,0F0F0F0F
    mov       ecx,eax
    shl       ecx,2
    or        ecx,eax
    mov       eax,ecx
    and       eax,33333333
    mov       ecx,edx
    shl       ecx,2
    or        ecx,edx
    mov       edx,ecx
    and       edx,33333333
    lea       ecx,[rax+rax]
    or        ecx,eax
    mov       eax,ecx
    and       eax,55555555
    lea       ecx,[rdx+rdx]
    or        ecx,edx
    mov       edx,ecx
    and       edx,55555555
    add       eax,eax
    or        eax,edx
    ret
; Total bytes of code 119

## Int64 | .NET 7.0.5 (7.0.523.17405), X64 RyuJIT AVX2
; Ouroboros.Maths.BinaryIntegerFunctions.BitwisePair[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib],[System.Int64, System.Private.CoreLib]](Int32, Int32)
    movsxd    rax,edx
    movsxd    rdx,ecx
    mov       rcx,rax
    shl       rcx,10
    or        rax,rcx
    mov       rcx,0FFFF0000FFFF
    and       rax,rcx
    mov       rcx,rdx
    shl       rcx,10
    or        rdx,rcx
    mov       rcx,0FFFF0000FFFF
    and       rdx,rcx
    mov       rcx,rax
    shl       rcx,8
    or        rcx,rax
    mov       rax,0FF00FF00FF00FF
    and       rax,rcx
    mov       rcx,rdx
    shl       rcx,8
    or        rcx,rdx
    mov       rdx,0FF00FF00FF00FF
    and       rdx,rcx
    mov       rcx,rax
    shl       rcx,4
    or        rcx,rax
    mov       rax,0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F
    and       rax,rcx
    mov       rcx,rdx
    shl       rcx,4
    or        rcx,rdx
    mov       rdx,0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F
    and       rdx,rcx
    mov       rcx,rax
    shl       rcx,2
    or        rcx,rax
    mov       rax,3333333333333333
    and       rax,rcx
    mov       rcx,rdx
    shl       rcx,2
    or        rcx,rdx
    mov       rdx,3333333333333333
    and       rdx,rcx
    lea       rcx,[rax+rax]
    or        rcx,rax
    mov       rax,5555555555555555
    and       rax,rcx
    lea       rcx,[rdx+rdx]
    or        rcx,rdx
    mov       rdx,5555555555555555
    and       rdx,rcx
    add       rax,rax
    or        rax,rdx
    ret
; Total bytes of code 237

## UInt64 | .NET 7.0.5 (7.0.523.17405), X64 RyuJIT AVX2
; Ouroboros.Maths.BinaryIntegerFunctions.BitwisePair[[System.UInt32, System.Private.CoreLib],[System.UInt64, System.Private.CoreLib]](UInt32, UInt32)
    mov       eax,edx
    mov       edx,ecx
    mov       rcx,rax
    shl       rcx,10
    or        rax,rcx
    mov       rcx,0FFFF0000FFFF
    and       rax,rcx
    mov       rcx,rdx
    shl       rcx,10
    or        rdx,rcx
    mov       rcx,0FFFF0000FFFF
    and       rdx,rcx
    mov       rcx,rax
    shl       rcx,8
    or        rcx,rax
    mov       rax,0FF00FF00FF00FF
    and       rax,rcx
    mov       rcx,rdx
    shl       rcx,8
    or        rcx,rdx
    mov       rdx,0FF00FF00FF00FF
    and       rdx,rcx
    mov       rcx,rax
    shl       rcx,4
    or        rcx,rax
    mov       rax,0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F
    and       rax,rcx
    mov       rcx,rdx
    shl       rcx,4
    or        rcx,rdx
    mov       rdx,0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F
    and       rdx,rcx
    mov       rcx,rax
    shl       rcx,2
    or        rcx,rax
    mov       rax,3333333333333333
    and       rax,rcx
    mov       rcx,rdx
    shl       rcx,2
    or        rcx,rdx
    mov       rdx,3333333333333333
    and       rdx,rcx
    lea       rcx,[rax+rax]
    or        rcx,rax
    mov       rax,5555555555555555
    and       rax,rcx
    lea       rcx,[rdx+rdx]
    or        rcx,rdx
    mov       rdx,5555555555555555
    and       rdx,rcx
    add       rax,rax
    or        rax,rdx
    ret
; Total bytes of code 235
```

Comment: The manual unroll _maybe_ is fast and is a good thing. But there's no comments in the source that explain that. Consider adding an explanatory URL, or sentences, so a future maintenance engineer can verify that it _still_ benches faster under some future compiler. My concern is that we have added complexity for no gain, in the event that a compiler can automatically accomplish the unroll for us behind the scenes.

Comment: Good call! The unrolled version *is* significantly faster than the loop version; 'cause the key constants all get evaluated at compile time. One tried various different things to convince the compiler to unroll the loop but couldn't come up with anything that worked.

Comment: By the way, while it's not generic (and less portable), maybe you'd like to know about `Bmi2.X64.ParallelBitDeposit`, which lets you implement bit-interleaving in only a couple of instructions (very efficient on most *but not all* CPUs that support them, Zen2 implemented it badly)